# Cannot exit from Docker container

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I've got a container which I run as

```
docker run -it --rm --name <container_name> <image>:<tag>
```

normally, I fall into the container terminal from which I can exit with the `exit` command. Now, I have a DockerFile which ends with an entrypoint that runs a simple bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Add new user
groupadd -r $GROUP --gid $GROUPID
useradd -r $USER --uid $USERID --gid $GROUPID

# Launch application with new user
su - -c "python <path_to_script>/myscript.py" $USER
```

now, once my script ends, I expected to exit from the container but everything in the entrypoint bash script is ran again and again (say 10 times).

Why does my container have this behavior ?

Comment: How are you starting the container, can you share the exact command? are you using any process managers?

Comment: You've got the exact command `docker run -it --rm --name <container_name> <image>:<tag>`

Answer (score 0):

su manpage says:

> -, -l, --login
>              Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had
>              the user logged in directly

It spawns another shell from where you `exit` to comeback to parent `container` shell.

So changing

```
su - -c "python <path_to_script>/myscript.py" $USER
```

to

```
su "$USER" -c "python <path_to_script>/myscript.py"
```

might be the solution

---

<sup>**SIDENOTE :** The `-` together with `-c` doesn't make sense when your objective is just to execute some commands and finish the job</sup>

Comment: I agree, but I need the `-` because my container has anaconda installed and if I run without `-`, the python command does not link to anaconda but to python. When my python script exit, I would have expected that I returned to the root shell, but no. The python script is executed again and again

Answer (score 0):

This is how to change $USER inside your Dockerfile

```
# Add new user
RUN groupadd -r $GROUP --gid $GROUPID
RUN useradd -r $USER --uid $USERID --gid $GROUPID
RUN whoami
USER $USER
RUN whoami
```

prior to calling your shell script ... avoid using `su` in a Dockerfile

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I cannot put it in the DockerFile as I dont know the $USER when I build the image. Instead, I run a script as an ENTRYPOINT in which I add user and group.